# Which option among two is better for quality assessment?

Tags: probability

A company X needs to setup a product qualifying assessment committee. A product passes satisfaction by a YES confirmation from committee. Consider 2 following settings:

Option 1: Committee A including only one tester, with judgement accuracy p. (probability of correct judgment is p). Final sentence solely depends on this person judgment.

Option 2: Committee B including (2n + 1) members, among which are 2n testers of same accuracy p and 1 person who really just flips a fair-coin. Final sentence is decided by the majority of the votes.

Which option is better?

My first guess is that if $p<0.5 $ then the second option is definitely better. Also if $p>0.5$ then the first option is better. However, I could not go with any formally mathematically proof. Any help ?

Comment: Is the definition of $p$ the following: $p=P(\text{Tester sais No}\mid \text{Product is Faulty})=P(\text{Tester sais Yes}\mid \text{Product is OK})$?

Comment: Suppose $N$ products are tested, of which a fraction $q$ is faulty. Try to  write down the expected number of false positives and false negatives for both options.